# Javascript queryselectors not reading classes and ID when used in Django project

Tags: javascript, django

When I am working outside Django file, everything works fine with javascript reading classes and Ids like

```
document.querySelector('.class_name').addEventListener
```

But when loaded in Django projects it gives an error that eventlistner can't read NULL.

```
{% comment %} css file for contacts.html {% endcomment %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'info/js/for_recrs.js' %}"></script>
<link href="{% static 'info/css/for_recrs.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are declaring JS file in head, it will read it at that time itself without going through the HTML file. So, it reads null value of classes and ID. 
To avoid that you can declare script file just beforeend of body. 
OR
Use

```
window.onload = function() {
// do your stuff here.
}
```

It solved mine problem.